# How to call ML interface(functions) in C language

Tags: c, function, call, invoke, ml

I downloaded an opensource ML written software Unison from Internet and I hope to reuse part of the functions, but in my project I am using C language, is there a way to invoke ML written interface(functions) in C language? I hope there may be some ways to call external ML functions such as calling functions in Dlls using C++ on Windows.

I think there may be 3 possible ways:

1.Porting ML code to C.

2.Compiling ML code and invoke functions by function addresses in assembly language.

3.Using interprocess communication methods such as socket.

But I need more effective and efficient methods, there are proximately 30000 lines of ML code in the software.

Answer (score 2):

OCaml, the ML dialect in which Unison is written can be interfaced with C. There is a chapter in the reference manual that describes how it can be done: See http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual033.html#toc148 for the OCaml -> C way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I have already successfully built Unison in Visual Studio using OCaml compiler, and using the keyword Interfacting C with OCaml does help me in searching articles on invoking ML functions using C.